# Post-hoc table in statistics

Tags: spss, post-hoc, tukey-hsd-test

Please can someone help me interpret what the asterixis mean and how it is statistically different to the groups. I am so confused. I am doing a one way ANOVA looking at the effect of age on physical perpetration
[image]

Comment: The asterisks refer to statistically significant differences between your age groups in your post-hoc comparisons. (I) refers to the group to which the other groups (J) are compared to. For instance, the 12-13 group is statistically significantly different from 16-17 group but not from the 14-15 group.